# Complex string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, post, xmlhttprequest

I want to send my code to this API to compile. But it throws an error cuz there is \n in my string.
How can I set this string in my header?

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('code', 'n = 5\nwhile n > 0:\n   n -= 1\n   print(n)');
```

OR

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('code', 
'n = 5
while n > 0:
    n -= 1
    print(n)'
);
```

This is the error I get :

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'n = 5
while n > 0:
 n -= 1
 print(n)' is not a valid HTTP header field value.
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to send that code via a header and not as content of the request?

Comment: How can I do that? (just using javascript preferably)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowed to use symbol of new line in header value.

However, you can come up with a certain sequence of characters yourself, which the backend will regard as a newline character and automatically replace this sequence with a newline.

But it is better, of course, to transmit such things in the HTTP POST request body, and not in the headers.

Comment: I did that and used " xhr.open('POST', 'https://pooriya007.pythonanywhere.com/?code=' + Mycode); " to send my code, but still i cant use \n to go to next line.

Comment: Use this to send body : xhr.send(yourStringWithCode)
By the way, you can use fetch method.